# Dynamic highlight on geojson data between two maps in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm trying to link two sets of geojson data.
The two data sets are integrated in different "div" and therefore different maps. As can be seen on running the code below, the dynamic highlight works on both maps on hover the IDS.
However, what I want is to highlight the geojson object on the first map when hovering the corresponding geojson object from the second one. (Objects are linked by a same ID attibut).

```js
var dat1 =({
 "type" : "FeatureCollection",
 "name" : "NewFeatureType",
 "features" : [
  {
   "type" : "Feature",
   "geometry" : {
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "coordinates" : [
     [
      [ 7.2518485112, 47.1390738345 ],
      [ 7.2540323762, 47.1390773819 ],
      [ 7.2540289251, 47.1400723508 ],
      [ 7.2518450195, 47.1400688032 ],
      [ 7.2518485112, 47.1390738345 ]
     ]
    ]
   },
   "properties" : {
    "start_fid" : "504748"
   }
  },
  {
   "type" : "Feature",
   "geometry" : {
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "coordinates" : [
     [
      [ 7.2565390484, 47.130837227 ],
      [ 7.2633719322, 47.1308479108 ],
      [ 7.2633626773, 47.1336579369 ],
      [ 7.2565294346, 47.1336472526 ],
      [ 7.2565390484, 47.130837227 ]
     ]
    ]
   },
   "properties" : {
    "start_fid" : "862126"
   }
  }
 ]
});

var dat2 =({
 "type" : "FeatureCollection",
 "name" : "NewFeatureType",
 "features" : [
  {
   "type" : "Feature",
   "geometry" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ -19.9169596449, 32.1396903724 ]
   },
   "properties" : {
    "start_fid" : "504748"
   }
  },
  {
   "type" : "Feature",
   "geometry" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ -19.924214327, 32.1530002773 ]
   },
   "properties" : {
    "start_fid" : "862126"
   }
  }
 ]
});

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([47.132,7.260], 15);
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mtheisen/citei76iz005f2jpac8g7ilcl/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibXRoZWlzZW4iLCJhIjoiY2l0ZWk0NTBoMDVmMDJ0bXlyNmxzZ3RnMyJ9.fErHtcHVcTsHCLMPN1ZcQg', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mtheisen',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibXRoZWlzZW4iLCJhIjoiY2l0ZWk0NTBoMDVmMDJ0bXlyNmxzZ3RnMyJ9.fErHtcHVcTsHCLMPN1ZcQg'
}).addTo(mymap);

geojson1=L.geoJson(dat1, {style: style,
 onEachFeature: onEachFeature
 }).addTo(mymap);

var mymapid2 = L.map('mapid2',{ zoomControl:false }).setView([32.1378527851,-19.9229088608], 14);

geojson2=L.geoJson(dat2, {
 pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
  return L.circleMarker(latlng)
  },
  style: style,
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(mymapid2);

function style(feature) {
    return {
      fillColor: "red",
       weight: 1,
       opacity: 1,
       color: 'red',
       dashArray: '3',
       fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}
 var highlightStyle = {
    fillColor: "yellow",
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'yellow',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
 };


function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle(highlightStyle);
}

function resetHighlight(e) {
    geojson1.resetStyle(e.target);
}

function zoomTo(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    mymap.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
 name = feature.properties.start_fid;
  $('#mapid2').append('<li data-value="' + name + '">'+name+'</li>');
 layer._leaflet_id = name;
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomTo
    });
}

var hovered_id, layer;

$('#mapid2 li').on('mouseenter', function(e){
  hovered_id = $(e.target).data('value');
        //console.log(hovered_id);
  layer = geojson1.getLayer(hovered_id);
    layer2 = geojson2.getLayer(hovered_id);
  layer.setStyle(highlightStyle);
    layer2.setStyle(highlightStyle);
 }).on('mouseout', function(e){
    geojson1.resetStyle(layer);
  geojson2.resetStyle(layer2);
 });
```

```css
#mapid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  /*top: 0;*/
}

#mapid2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  /*top: 0;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mapid"></div>
  <div id="mapid2"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: you should first reduce the width of the li elements (with css), as for the moment when you hover the red circles, you are in fact triggering the hover of the li elements.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I try to apply the highlight on both maps and directly on hover the geometries (not the li element list). Hover on left map, highlight corresponding geometries on right map. Hover on right map highlight corresponding geometries on left map. The corresponding key that must return the objects to highlight on each maps is given by the "start_fid" attribute from each geojson data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my brother for the solution!

```js
    var dat1 =({
       "type" : "FeatureCollection",
       "name" : "NewFeatureType",
       "features" : [
          {
             "type" : "Feature",
             "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                   [
                      [ 7.2518485112, 47.1390738345 ],
                      [ 7.2540323762, 47.1390773819 ],
                      [ 7.2540289251, 47.1400723508 ],
                      [ 7.2518450195, 47.1400688032 ],
                      [ 7.2518485112, 47.1390738345 ]
                   ]
                ]
             },
             "properties" : {
                "start_fid" : "504748",
                "group_fid" : "1"
             }
          },
          {
             "type" : "Feature",
             "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                   [
                      [ 7.2565390484, 47.130837227 ],
                      [ 7.2633719322, 47.1308479108 ],
                      [ 7.2633626773, 47.1336579369 ],
                      [ 7.2565294346, 47.1336472526 ],
                      [ 7.2565390484, 47.130837227 ]
                   ]
                ]
             },
             "properties" : {
                "start_fid" : "862126",
                "group_fid" : "2"
             }
          },
          {
             "type" : "Feature",
             "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                   [
                     [ 7.2585, 47.1345 ],
                     [ 7.2633, 47.1345 ],
                     [ 7.2633, 47.1366 ],
                     [ 7.2585, 47.1366 ],
                     [ 7.2585, 47.1345 ]
                   ]
                ]
             },
             "properties" : {
                "start_fid" : "99999",
                "group_fid" : "2"
             }
          }
       ]
    });

    var dat2 =({
       "type" : "FeatureCollection",
       "name" : "NewFeatureType",
       "features" : [
          {
             "type" : "Feature",
             "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -19.9169596449, 32.1396903724 ]
             },
             "properties" : {
                "start_fid" : "504748",
                "group_fid" : "1"
             }
          },
          {
             "type" : "Feature",
             "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -19.924214327, 32.1530002773 ]
             },
             "properties" : {
                "start_fid" : "862126",
                "group_fid" : "2"
             }
          }
       ]
    });

    var defaultStyle = {
       fillColor: "red",
       weight: 1,
       opacity: 1,
       color: 'red',
       dashArray: '3',
       fillOpacity: 0.7
    };

    var highlightStyle = {
       fillColor: "yellow",
       weight: 2,
       opacity: 1,
       color: 'yellow',
       dashArray: '3',
       fillOpacity: 0.7
    };

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([47.132,7.260], 15);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mtheisen/citei76iz005f2jpac8g7ilcl/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibXRoZWlzZW4iLCJhIjoiY2l0ZWk0NTBoMDVmMDJ0bXlyNmxzZ3RnMyJ9.fErHtcHVcTsHCLMPN1ZcQg', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mtheisen',
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibXRoZWlzZW4iLCJhIjoiY2l0ZWk0NTBoMDVmMDJ0bXlyNmxzZ3RnMyJ9.fErHtcHVcTsHCLMPN1ZcQg'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    geojson1=L.geoJson(dat1, {style: defaultStyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var mymap2 = L.map('mapid2').setView([32.1378527851,-19.9229088608], 14);

    geojson2=L.geoJson(dat2, {
       pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng)
          },
      style: defaultStyle,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(mymap2);


    function highlightFeature(e) {
       manageHighlight(e, dat1, geojson1, highlightStyle);
       manageHighlight(e, dat2, geojson2, highlightStyle);
    }

    function resetHighlight(e) {
       manageHighlight(e, dat1, geojson1, defaultStyle);
       manageHighlight(e, dat2, geojson2, defaultStyle);
    }

    function manageHighlight(e, dataBloc, geojson, style){
       for (var i = 0; i < dataBloc.features.length; i++) {
          if(dataBloc.features[i].properties.group_fid == e.target.feature.properties.group_fid){
             var layer = geojson.getLayer(dataBloc.features[i].properties.start_fid);
             layer.setStyle(style);
          }
       }
    }

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
       name = feature.properties.start_fid;
       layer._leaflet_id = name;
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
        });
    }
```

```css
#mapid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  /*top: 0;*/
}

#mapid2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  /*top: 0;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mapid"></div>
  <div id="mapid2"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```